# Xamarin Forms Disposed Textview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Been getting this exception a lot in my Xamarin Forms Project (android). The problem is that the stacktrace gives little information on how to reproduce, or where does it occur.

```
Xamarin caused by: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsTextView'.
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable self)<be2616b5140e4cbb8821649c795cfe62>:0
Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod(string encodedMember, IJavaPeerable self, JniArgumentValue* parameters)<be2616b5140e4cbb8821649c795cfe62>:0
Android.Widget.TextView.set_TextFormatted(ICharSequence value)<ec6bb63c41624773b5cc1eb2222982af>:0
Android.Widget.TextView.set_Text(string value)<ec6bb63c41624773b5cc1eb2222982af>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer.UpdateText()<d572ae0ccf89437fad1de1370c623a06>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer.OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)<d572ae0ccf89437fad1de1370c623a06>:0
<Module>.invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs(object, PropertyChangedEventArgs)(wrapper delegate-invoke)
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindableObject.BindablePropertyContext context, object value, bool currentlyApplying, BindableObject.SetValueFlags attributes, bool silent)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, object value, BindableObject.SetValueFlags attributes, BindableObject.SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore(object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property, bool fromTarget)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply(object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Apply(object newContext, BindableObject bindObj, BindableProperty targetProperty)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings(object oldContext, bool skipBindingContext)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings(object oldContext)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext(BindableObject bindable, object value)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext(Element child, object context)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged()<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged()<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext(BindableObject bindable, object value)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext(Element child, object context)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged()<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.Cell.OnBindingContextChanged()<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.BindingContextPropertyBindingPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindableObject.BindablePropertyContext context, object value, bool currentlyApplying, BindableObject.SetValueFlags attributes, bool silent)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, object value, BindableObject.SetValueFlags attributes, BindableObject.SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, object value, bool fromStyle, bool checkAccess)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, object value)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.set_BindingContext(object value)<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedItemsList<TView, TItem>.<UnhookItem>d__140.MoveNext()<7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state)<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()<67dcc9194d6a4f4f97ac27121b4304c3>:0
```

Comment: Are you using a custom renderer involving a TextView? Did this occur after adding a certain piece of code?

Comment: Yes, I have 2 renderes (A custom ImageButton and custom Entry Renderer) which have Labels inside. However it is hard to know which one may cause the problem. As I said, I have no context regarding where does the exception occurs.

Comment: I understand, but if you don't have any context, we have even less because we have no code to look at and have no idea what you are trying to do. Try to eliminate options by setting breakpoints in your renderers and going through them or commenting out lines and see which one causes a problem. Then, if you still don't know what is going on post your problem with the relevant code for us to look at.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Gerald Versluis, we know nothing about what you're doing, only thing we know is that you have a `TextView`, and you try to use it after it get disposed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

Create a CustomLabel and CustomLabelRenderer

Your Renderer code in the Android project should look like...

```
public class CustomLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is very hacky but it works for me 100%

Answer (score 1):

This issues mostly occur because of TextView / TextField inside ListView. If you have the same case you can change the ***CachingStrategy*** to ***RecycleElement***.

Example:

```
 <ListView x:Name="AccountDetailsList"
                        StyleId="AccountDetailsListID"
                        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding AccountDetails}"
```