# Cannot access a disposed object exception in xamarin forms project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin Forms (Forms version: 2.3.4.231) project.
The app works fine in iOS whereas in Android, I get random crashes. From the crash logs, it seems like its an internal crash but I don't know where to start.

I know I don't have enough information in the app. But can somebody help me to understand the issue better?

Here is the crash log:

```
    11/07/2017 PM 12:33:13.216: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsTextView'.  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf (Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self) [0x00030] in <b1a275385773449f855cd147e39ca2c4>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00001] in <b1a275385773449f855cd147e39ca2c4>:0 
  at Android.Widget.TextView.set_TextFormatted (Java.Lang.ICharSequence value) [0x00028] in <37dcd078418a4ced956136dfaeb51ee2>:0 
  at Android.Widget.TextView.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00013] in <37dcd078418a4ced956136dfaeb51ee2>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer.UpdateText () [0x00098] in <1481f85a917c4f2b882ea161e9bc082f>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.LabelRenderer.OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x000c5] in <1481f85a917c4f2b882ea161e9bc082f>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00012] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x000fb] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (System.Object sourceObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x001f9] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (System.Boolean fromTarget) [0x0003e] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.<PropertyChanged>b__47_0 () [0x00000] in <0f1ce60dbc6b4e24af01294c7acf41c6>:0 
  at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in <37dcd078418a4ced956136dfaeb51ee2>:0 
  at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in <37dcd078418a4ced956136dfaeb51ee2>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:0cbcd7f2-854c-44ac-8467-eb8b42716bc1 (intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: Do you have some relevant code where this exception seems to occur?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much information. I am not sure where this crash happens. I even tried setting exception breakpoints. But the app doesn't stop at anything.

Comment: But still, what is the code/XAML for the page it is trying to show? What code is involved in that page? Something is happening with a `FormsTextView`, do you have any custom renderers in place? We need more info than you're providing right now to be able to say anything useful.

Comment: Hi, I update a Forms application this morning and I have the same issue with seems to throw when an Entry is in the page ( I do not have more information yet )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an issue many are having ([1](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93724/disposed-object-textview), [2](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105958/app-is-getting-crash-randomly-on-android), [3](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99819/cannot-access-a-disposed-object-object-name-xamarin-forms-platform-android-formstextview), [4](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92102/system-objectdisposedexception)). It may be fixed in 2.3.5 so try installing one of the 2.3.5 XF libraries and see if the problem goes away.

Also there are a few answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389037/xamarin-forms-disposed-textview) that may work for you.

1. Create a `Entry` and/or `Label` renderer, override `OnAttachedToWindow` and `Dispose` and catch the exception.
2. Try setting `ListView.CachingStrategy` to `RecycleElement`

Comment: ListView.CachingStrategy to RecycleElement worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we hit this bug on Xamarin.Forms 3.6.X. This may be fixed in 4.X, I don't know, but in the meantime we were able to solve it by creating our own LabelRenderer as @hvaughan3 suggested.

To save some typing, here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(Your.Namespace.Renderers.YourLabelRenderer))]
namespace Your.Namespace.Renderers
{
    public class YourLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public YourLabelRenderer(Android.Content.Context context) : base(context) { }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            }
            catch (System.ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //This is addressing a crash in Xamarin forums 3.6 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still havibng this problem XF4.0